# Vaadin DateField in 24 hour mode

Tags: java, vaadin

[image]

Could anybody help me with this problem?
I'l like to use Vaadin's DateField in 24 hour mode, not in am and pm mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately overriding 12/24h clock setting to something else than Locale says is not supported.

To add such a service, I would inherit InlineDateField and add methods for overriding 12-24 clock setting. On the client-side one must take a look at VCalendarPanel.java and add pass this setting to if statement that calls getDateTimeService().isTwelveHourClock().

On the other hand - maybe it would be easier to somehow define a custom locale to the set of all supported locales.

Third hacky alternative would be to override LocaleService.java class in the GWT copilation process and ensure that isTwelveHourClock() returns false.

(did not test any of these approaches)

Comment: Have successed according to the first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setLocale() method to customize the presentation of the date format.

```
// German language specified with ISO 639-1 language
// code and ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code. 
date.setLocale(new Locale("de", "DE"));
```

More information [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/559334) and [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.datefield.html).

Comment: Thanks.However,I'd like to display the UI in Chinese or English, not Germany.How can I do it?

Comment: the locale controls the display settings of a date and time of a specific language or country. So in your case I recommend you to use UK for United Kingdom. They use the 24h time format.

Comment: So,there is no solution to control Chinese display settings?
What a pitty! Maybe that is a bug.

Comment: well if you define Chinese as the locale you will have the am/pm clock.